# Wrap <div> inside <a> tag

Tags: nodes, input-formats

This is valid HTML5. Yet Drupal 7 seems to ignore it.

This is what is entered into the node (using FULL HTML and no WYSIWG)

```
<a style="display:block; height: 50px; width: 200px" href="http://somewhere.com">
  <div class="xyz">My div contents</div>
</a>
```

And this is what the garbage rendered:

```
<p><a style="display:block; height: 50px; width: 200px" href="http://somewhere.com"></a></p>
<div class="xyz">My div contents</div>
<p></p>
```

Any success in beating Drupal into submission when it comes to respecting valid HTML5?

Comment: "Drupal" doesn't enforce any HTML standard. *You* can selectively apply various text filters, however. What text filters do you have enabled for Full HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any success in beating Drupal into submission when it comes to
>   respecting valid HTML5?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably it is also caused from converting line breaks into HTML.

Comment: Genius! I have overlooked that horribly labeled "option", and spent copious hours trying different work-arounds  for far longer then I care to admit!

--- Problem solved. Thanks!

BTW - Nice nice job of documenting the solution. Very few people take the time (or apparently lack the skill) to do that.